# JS remove class Name dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a requirement to remove a class name dynamically via js.

The reason to do so is that I'm trying to remove the icon of sorting a specific column from a table.

When I inspect the element - I see I have ng-class with the same class name as the class attribute.

I don't have any access to the angular file - since it's a third-party app, but I can write some JS in it.

```
<th title="" ng-repeat="$column in $columns" ng-class="{
   'sortable': $column.sortable(this),
   'sort-asc': params.sorting()[$column.sortable(this)]=='asc',
   'sort-desc': params.sorting()[$column.sortable(this)]=='desc'
   }" class="col_poi_Id_356 sortable">
</th>
```

When I'm removing the "sortable" from the class manually from the developer console - It works great.

But when I'm trying to do: `element.remove("sortable");` it removes the "sortable" both from the class and from the ng-class and its causes unwanted behavior.

I want to remove a class name only from the class attribute without touching the ng-class.

is that possible?

I don't have much knowledge in JS, but I tried to find a solution on the google but didn't find one.

any help, including links, will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `element.remove()` seems like you're removing an element. Have you tried `element.classList.remove('sortable');`?

Comment: Can't believe what a silly mistake. Thank you